# Using Python and Regex to extract different formats of dates

Tags: python, regex

I have the following code to match the dates

```
import re
date_reg_exp2 = re.compile(r'\d{2}([-/.])(\d{2}|[a-zA-Z]{3})\1(\d{4}|\d{2})|\w{3}\s\d{2}[,.]\s\d{4}')
matches_list = date_reg_exp2.findall("23-SEP-2015 and 23-09-2015 and 23-09-15 and Sep 23, 2015")
print matches_list
```

The output I expect is

```
["23-SEP-2015","23-09-2015","23-09-15","Sep 23, 2015"]
```

What I am getting is:

```
[('-', 'SEP', '2015'), ('-', '09', '2015'), ('-', '09', '15'), ('', '', '')]
```

Please check the link for `regex` [here](http://regexr.com/3ccth).

Comment: I think your first `(` may be in the wrong place - the first two numbers are not captured, the first thing you've told it to capture is the `[-/.]` sequence

Comment: Really, it's little difficult for regex to do that...what about just use `"23-SEP-2015 and 23-09-2015 and 23-09-15 and Sep 23, 2015".split(' and ')` in this case?

Comment: In this case it works but the input string is not actually separated by `and`. It can be `This string is 23-09-2015 and It can also be something`. I need a match saying `['23-09-2015']`

Comment: @SimonFraser I'm not good with `regex` If you can help me with the above expression that would be great.

Comment: @PalepuKartheek have a look at the regex in my answer. it will take care of the string from which you want to extract the date.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem you have is that [`re.findall`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.findall) returns captured texts only excluding Group 0 (the whole match). Since you need the whole match (Group 0), you just need to use [`re.finditer`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.finditer) and grab the `group()` value:

```
matches_list = [x.group() for x in date_reg_exp2.finditer("23-SEP-2015 and 23-09-2015 and 23-09-15 and Sep 23, 2015")]
```

See [IDEONE demo](https://ideone.com/ZOsLMb)

> **`re.findall(pattern, string, flags=0)`**
> Return all non-overlapping matches of *pattern* in string, as a list of strings... ***If one or more groups are present in the pattern, return a list of groups; this will be a list of tuples if the pattern has more than one group.***
>
> **`re.finditer(pattern, string, flags=0)`**
> Return an [iterator](https://docs.python.org/2/glossary.html#term-iterator) yielding [`MatchObject`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.MatchObject) instances over all non-overlapping matches for the RE *pattern* in string.

Answer (score 2):

You could try this regex

```
date_reg_exp2 = re.compile(r'(\d{2}(/|-|\.)\w{3}(/|-|\.)\d{4})|([a-zA-Z]{3}\s\d{2}(,|-|\.|,)?\s\d{4})|(\d{2}(/|-|\.)\d{2}(/|-|\.)\d+)')
```

Then use `re.finditer()`

```
for m in re.finditer(date_reg_exp2,"23-SEP-2015 and 23-09-2015 and 23-09-15 and Sep 23, 2015"):
print m.group()
```

The Output will be

> 23-SEP-2015
>   23-09-2015
>   23-09-15
>   Sep 23, 2015

Comment: Your regex also captures something like this (which I don't need) - `55.123.4567`. Also `/` says "Unescaped Forward Slash". So I guess you need to use `\/`.

Comment: I think `.` does not occur in your dates so that need not be included in the regex and for `/` you can use `\/`

Comment: In the example I have given above - `.` doesn't occur but in real-time cases a lot of `.` occur (atleast in my case).

Comment: Some cases which I can think of: `dd-mm-yyyy` `dd/mm/yyyy` `dd.mm.yyyy` `dd-mon-yyyy` `dd/mon/yyyy` `dd.mon.yyyy` `Mon dd, yyyy` `Mon dd. yyyy`

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
# The first (\d{2}-([A-Z]{3}|\d{2})-(\d{4}|\d{2})) group tries to match the first three types of dates
# rest will match the last type
dates = "23-SEP-2015 and 23-09-2015 and 23-09-15 and Sep 23, 2015"
for x in re.finditer('((\d{2}-([A-Z]{3}|\d{2})-(\d{4}|\d{2}))|([a-zA-Z]{3}\s\d{1,2},\s\d{4}))', dates):
    print x.group(1)
```